# Django: NoReverseMatch at /patient/1/

Tags: html, django

I have this **urls.py** in cabinet app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register_patient/', views.registerPatient,name='register_patient'),
    path('register_booking/', views.registerBooking,name='register_booking'),
    path('register_visit/<int:id>/', views.registerVisit,name='register_visit'),
    path('<int:id>/', views.detail_patient),
]
```

before adding the 4th `path('register_visit/<<int:id>>/'),` the `views.detail_patient` was working well but now when I add this 4th path the `views.detail_patient` didn't work and I get this error:

> `NoReverseMatch at /patient/1/`

So my problem is that I can't use '`<<int:id>>`' more than one time and in my code I have the index page which shows the list of patients and every patient has a button 'details' which will take me to the 5th `path(('<<int:id>>/', views.detail_patient))` and in this template I have a button '***Nouvelle Chirurgie***' which will take me to the 4th `path(('register_visit/<<int:id>>/', views.registerVisit,name='register_visit'))`.
In **index.html** this the Details button:

```
<a href="{{field.id}}/" class="btn btn-warning">Details</a>
```

And in **detail_patient.html** this is the 'Nouvelle Chirurgie' button

```
<a href="{% url 'register_visit' %}{{patients.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Nouvelle Chirurgie</a>
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
<a href="{% url 'register_visit' %}{{patients.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Nouvelle Chirurgie</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{% url 'register_visit' patients.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Nouvelle Chirurgie</a>
```

i hope that patients is not a queryset if it is you should iterate over it using forloop for this code above to work.
urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register_patient/', views.registerPatient,name='register_patient'),
    path('register_booking/', views.registerBooking,name='register_booking'),
    path('register_visit/<int:id>/', views.registerVisit,name='register_visit'),
    path('<int:id>/', views.detail_patient,name='detail_patient'),
]
```

in detail_patient i added a name='detail_patient'.

```
<a href="{% url 'detail_patient' field.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">Details</a>
```

field.id is just an example you should replace with the instance you want.

Comment: Perfect, your solution is working well thank you so much. I'm sorry I can't accept your solution because I don't have 15 reputation yet

Comment: @AkramBaklouti i am happy i was able to help you)